# embedded pdo losing connection in php

Tags: php, pdo

I am loosing my $conn 'Notice: Undefined variable: conn in .. routines.php' I cannot figure out why. The index.php calls the session.php which grabs the db.php and routine.php BUT the routine.php would not accept the $conn as you can see below. I am eager to learn, could you guide me in the right direction?

index.php

```
<?php require_once("session.php");?>
```

session.php

```
<?php session_start();
require_once("db.php");
require_once("routines.php");
$data=sql_source("table","name")
?>
```

routine.php

```
<?php
echo $status; THIS WORKS
function sql_source($table,$name){
    $sql="SELECT ".$name." FROM ".$table;
    $res=$conn->query($sql); **ERROR MESSAGE**:Notice: Undefined variable: conn in
    return $res;
}
?>
```

db.php

```
<php?
    $initlocation="mysql:dbname=dbname;host=local";
    $username="user";
    $pwadat="pass";

    try{
         $conn = new PDO($initlocation, $username, $pwadat);
         $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
         echo "</br>Conncetion is established</br>"; / THIS WORKS.
         $status = $conn->getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_CONNECTION_STATUS);
        }
    catch(PDOException $e){
               echo "Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage();   
        }
    ?>
```

Comment: ..because sql_source() doesn't use the global variable $conn?

Comment: thank you for your comment could you guide my how to make it work?

Comment: Added my 2 cents as an answer.

Comment: Thank you very much I am going to test it.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pass `$conn` variable to `sql_source` function:

```
function sql_source($table,$name,$conn){
    $sql="SELECT ".$name." FROM ".$table;
    $res=$conn->query($sql); **ERROR MESSAGE**:Notice: Undefined variable: conn in
    return $res;
}
```

and then call this function:

```
$data=sql_source("table","name", $conn);
```

you should read more about variable scope: [Variable scope](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: Thank you very much for that I am going to test it.

Answer (score 1):

## Alt 1

The function sql_source() in your code doesn't have a local variable `$conn`, in your code the variable is defined on the global level. PHP doesn't "pull in" global variables by default, instead you have to tell it to do it using

```
function sql_source($table, $name) {
    global $conn;
    $conn->setAttribute(...);
    ...
}
```

The `global` line adds the global variable to the local scope.

## Alt 2

Send the variable as an argument to the function:

```
function sql_source($table, $name, $conn) {
    $conn->setAttribute(...);
    ...
}

sql_source("table", "name", $conn); // Calling the function
```

Comment: thank you for your help I was reading about global and everyone against it.

Comment: @AndrasSebestyen Yes, as a rule of thumb parameters should be used instead.